# How to define a MuRef instance for this nontrivial expression type?

Tags: haskell, data-reify

Consider a toy embedded language:

```
data Expr =
    App Expr Expr 
  | Lam Pat Expr
  | Case Expr [(Pat, Expr)]
```

I want to observe any implicit sharing in `Expr` expressions by using [data-reify](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-reify).  To do that, I need a proxy type corresponding to graph nodes:

```
data ExprF e =
    AppF e e
  | LamF Pat e
  | Case e [(Pat, e)]
```

and an instance for the `MuRef` class.  I can provide a definition for `mapDeRef` easily for the `App` and `Lam` constructors, but I'm not sure how to deal with the definition corresponding to `Case`:

```
instance MuRef Expr where
  type DeRef Expr = ExprF
  mapDeRef f (App e0 e1)  = AppF <$> f e0 <*> f e1
  mapDeRef f (Lam p e)    = LamF p <$> f e
  mapDeRef f (Case e pes) = Case <$> f e <*> ?
```

Judging by an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694997/how-to-reify-a-list-of-data-using-data-reify/11696832#11696832), it looks like it might be possible to make this happen by adding a few clever constructors to `ExprF` along with corresponding `MuRef` instances for something like `(Pat, Expr)` and `[(Pat, Expr)]`.  I tried that:

```
data ExprF e =
    AppF e e
  | LamF Pat e
  | Pair (Pat, e)
  | CaseF e [(Pat, e)]
  | Cons e e
  | Nil

instance MuRef (Pat, Expr) where
  type DeRef (Pat, Expr) = ExprF
  mapDeRef f (p, e)      = Pair <$> ((,) <$> pure p <*> f e)

instance MuRef [(Pat, Expr)] where
  type DeRef [(Pat, Expr)] = ExprF
  mapDeRef _ []            = pure Nil
  mapDeRef f (pe:pes)      = Cons <$> f pe <*> f pes
```

But no luck there when it comes to the original `mapDeRef` binding for `Case`:

```
instance MuRef Expr where
  ...
  mapDeRef f (Case e pes)  = Case <$> f e <*> f pes

Could not deduce (u ~ [(Pat, u)])
from the context (Applicative f)
  bound by the type signature for
             mapDeRef :: Applicative f =>
                         (forall b. (MuRef b, DeRef Expr ~ DeRef b) => b -> f u)
                         -> Expr -> f (DeRef Expr u)
```

Is it possible to define `mapDeRef` properly for the `Case` pattern?  Is there something simple I'm overlooking?

Comment: Your code works if you change `CaseF` to `CaseF e e`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance can be defined for the original type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, TupleSections #-}

import qualified Data.Traversable as T
import Data.Reify
import Control.Applicative

data Expr =
    App Expr Expr 
  | Lam Pat Expr
  | Case Expr [(Pat, Expr)]

data ExprF e =
    AppF e e
  | LamF Pat e
  | CaseF e [(Pat, e)]

data Pat -- placeholder

instance MuRef Expr where
    type DeRef Expr = ExprF
    mapDeRef f (App e0 e1)  = AppF <$> f e0 <*> f e1
    mapDeRef f (Lam p e)    = LamF p <$> f e
    mapDeRef f (Case e pes) = CaseF <$> f e <*> T.traverse (\(pat, exp) -> (pat,) <$> f exp) pes
```

I am not familiar with `Data.Reify`, I just filled in the instance definition following the types, so I'm not sure if the semantics will correspond to what you want here; but the instance can be definitely done.

Side note: using `lens` the implementation becomes really clear:

```
import Control.Lens
-- code omitted
mapDeRef f (Case e pes) = CaseF <$> f e <*> (traverse . _2) f pes
```

Comment: @jozefg you mean in order to use the instance? (for me this typechecks as it is)

Comment: Oh I'm silly, you're using it on the list so you won't need such an instance.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.  I first tried mucking around with traverse but hadn't gotten anything working.  Cheers.

Comment: I see you added the `lens` example; I had been trying the same with `CaseF <$> f e <*> over (traverse._2) f pes`, which obviously doesn't typecheck.  Almost had it. ;)

Comment: @jtobin you should be using the TypedHoles feature of GHC 7.8 in case like this, it is an enormous help.

Comment: `_2` is the same as `traverse` for 2-tuples. So `(traverse . traverse) f pes` would work too.